# Search github pull requests always filters for me as author

Tags: github

When I attempt to search definitelytyped for pull requests containing some search text, it always adds a filter to specify me as the author, so I get no results.

On the Pull Requests page, I set the filter to is:open and a put a search text string into the search bar at the top, then clicked on the Pull requests link next to the search bar. However, I get no finds because the filter has been changed to include author: NCARalph.

This even happens when I try a negated author filter, e.g. -author: NCARalph. It changes the -author to author.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the way to do this is to put the search into the filters field, not the search field.

If you are in a repo searching for pull requests that contain the string "XYZZY", putting "XYZZY" in the search field at the top marked This Repository and hitting the Pull Requests selection seems to always force in an author field for you. However, if you enter "XYZZY is:pr" in the Filters field, it doesn't force in an authors filter and will find all matching pull requests.

This seems a bit bizarre to me, but apparently that's how it works.